# Center Navbar / Brand for Smaller Displays

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Apologies if this has already been asked, but I am trying to center my navbar if the user shrinks their display.

Right now I have the navbar-items floated to the right and the brand on the left for large displays. These remain on the right and left as the display shrinks.

I'd like for them to be centered instead when the display shrinks.

---

For large displays this is what I want. (What I'm getting now)

[image: Left float / right float for large displays]

For small displays I want the navbar and brand to be centered. (Not what I'm getting right now)

[image: Stacked un-centered for smaller displays]

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best way to do it, but you could just use an image instead and then apply the "center-block" class to it

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
    </div>
```

Comment: Hm. The center-block is useful, but I think changing the menu to an image would introduce more problems... But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: All its doing is replacing the brand with an image, ive used it multiple times, but ive never needed to center the brand/img

Comment: Hm. This might work... but it doesn't solve the navbar centering :-/